# CakePHP 3 - Can you set default conditions for a table?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Is there a way in CakePHP to set default conditions for a table?

For example, my table has a `deleted` table with a boolean value of 0 or 1. I would like to limit the application by default to only select rows where `deleted = 0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implement the beforeFind() callback of the table and add your condition there.

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#beforefind

> Cake\ORM\Table::beforeFind(Event $event, Query $query, ArrayObject $options, boolean $primary)
>
> The Model.beforeFind event is fired before each find operation. By stopping the event and supplying a return value you can bypass the find operation entirely. Any changes done to the $query instance will be retained for the rest of the find. The $primary parameter indicates whether or not this is the root query, or an associated query. All associations participating in a query will have a Model.beforeFind event triggered. For associations that use joins, a dummy query will be provided. In your event listener you can set additional fields, conditions, joins or result formatters. These options/features will be copied onto the root query.
>
> You might use this callback to restrict find operations based on a user’s role, or make caching decisions based on the current load.

Comment: Where is the beforeFind() method actually located and documented? I can't find it in the API documentation and would like to know more about it rather than just the method signature and a description.

Comment: Well, then I recommend you to read the *whole* event chapter of the book as well. You need to implement that method in the table object with the signature because it's an event callback as the book tells you.